# Per-user "Include Directories" in NetBeans 7.2

Tags: c++, netbeans-7, include-path

Let's assume that two developers have the same include files in different directories on their PCs.  How then can they customize the `Include Directories` parameter of a C++ project to take this difference into account?

I have tried setting an environment variable (for example: `MY_INCLUDE_DIR`) and adding it (either `${MY_INCLUDE_DIR}` or `%MY_INCLUDE_DIR%`) to the `Include Directories` list, but NetBeans displays an error when I include a header.

I'm sure that the environment variable is properly set because if I add it to the compiler command line (`"-I${MY_INCLUDE_DIR}"`) then the code compiles even if NetBeans does not find the header.

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio doesn't recognise environment variables unfortunately.  It is a glaring omission.  You could consider using Sysinternals' [junction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/junction) utility to make the desired header files directory appear to be in the same place regardless of its physical location.  This approach solves a similar problem for me.

Comment: Meta comment: assuming I have guessed right, you could do with a visual-studio tag there.

Comment: @PaulSanders I will test your suggestion, thanks.

Actually, the question relates to Netbeans, as indicated by the `netbeans-7` tag.  I have updated the title to avoid further misundertandings.

Comment: OK, sorry, my mistake, but if that doesn't recognise environment variables either then the same trick should work for you.